# Помогите прочитать код

Tags: java

Не могу понять почему так:

```
class Puzzle {
  private static boolean condition;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String answer = "Какое самое главное число во вселенной?";

    byte initialSum = 120;
    short additionalSum = 31999;
    int secretSum = 162;

    byte number = (byte) (initialSum * additionalSum + secretSum);

    if (!condition) {
      answer = "Ответ на главный вопрос жизни, вселенной и всего такого: ";
      System.out.println(answer + number);
    } else {
      System.out.println(answer);
    }
 


//Ответ на главный вопрос жизни, вселенной и всего такого: 42
```

Я новичок и просто не могу додуматься почему 42:)

Answer (score 1):

Потому что преобразование к `byte` берёт младшие 8 бит, грубо говоря, вычисляет значение по модулю 256, и `condition` гарантировано инициализируются `false`.

Это если вопрос не за то, почему именно 42. (Да, у Вас закрывающая фигурная скобочка - отклеилась!)

Answer (score 1):

Явное приведении [простых типов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Основной код - `byte number = (byte) (initialSum * additionalSum + secretSum);` будет выполняться в следующем порядке:

1. "Выравнивание" типов параметров (xxxSum) до int, как наиболее "толстого" из них.
2. Вычисление выражения: `120 * 31999 + 162 = 3 840 042` в десятичной или `3A 98 2A` в шестнадцатиричной системе счисления
3. Явное приведение int к byte, в результате от 32 бит (4 байт) остаётся только младший один байт, с содержимым `2A`, что в переводе на десятичную будет `42`.
4. condition - boolean переменная, имеющая по умолчанию значение `false`

Comment: пропробую обьяснить простыми словами -byte = от -128 до 127  есть такая штука, как переполнение  пишем в ide byte num=127; System.out.println(++num);и получаем вывод -128 мы доходим до "границы значений" 127 и дальше ити некуда, и поэтому мы начинам с самого начала от -128 и идём дальше, и так пока не остановимся. (byte) (initialSum * additionalSum)  // 120 * 31999 =-120 
  мы крутимся от -128 до 127 пока не закончится число  120 * 31999 и в конце прибавляем `int secretSum = 162;`
  а `-120 + 162 =  42

Comment: @стасевич https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2

Comment: и??? я что-то неправильно написал?

Comment: @стасевич да. Вычисление идёт с типом int и уже после всех операций кастуется в byte. А вы пишете, что изначально и умножение и сложение работают с byte. `the operation is carried out using 32-bit precision, and the result of the numerical operator is of type int. If either operand is not an int, it is first widened to type int by numeric promotion.`

Comment: я вас понял....в полном ответе это писал, но вопрос закрыли, и пришлось влазить в размер комментария....